# Mailto link not working in ios 5 using cordova

Tags: html, cordova, kendo-ui

I have developed a mobile application using cordova 3.1. In android and IOS 7 mailto link is perfectly working. But in IOS 5 it is not working after i upgraded cordova form 3.0 to 3.1.

```
<a href="mailto:some@example.com">Example</a>
```

It is showing

Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can't be shown. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this on ios device

```
 $('.anchortag').on("click", function (e) {

        var emailBody = "Body of Content";

        var subject = "This is test Subject";
        document.location.href = "mailto:customer@email.com?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + emailBody;

    });
```

OR

```
    <div class="bottom-row">
       <a href="#" id="submitForm" title="Submit Answers">Submit Answers</a>
    </div>

    <form id="mailtoForm" action="mailto:test@gmail.com" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="Cc" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="Bcc" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="Body" value="">
        <input type="submit" style="display:none">
    </form>



    $("#submitForm").on("click",function (e) {


       var emailBody = "Body of Content";

       var subject = "This is test Subject";

        $("#mailtoForm").find("input[name=Subject]").val(subject);
        $("#mailtoForm").find("input[name=Body]").val(emailBody);
        $("#mailtoForm").submit();


    });
```

Comment: I tried this...but it is not working...when i click on the link the same error is showing up..any other suggestion?

Comment: This is working in IOS 7...but not in IOS 5...same error